# beautiful soup article scraping

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab all of the p tags within the body of an article. I was wondering if someone could explain why my code was wrong and how I could improve it. Below is the URL of the article and the relevant code. Thanks for any insight you can provide.

url: http://www.france24.com/en/20140310-libya-seize-north-korea-crude-oil-tanker-rebels-port-rebels/

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Ask user to enter URL
url = raw_input("Please enter a valid URL: ")

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

# retrieve all of the paragraph tags
body = soup.find("div", {'class':'bd'}).get_text()
for tag in body:
    p = soup.find_all('p')
    print str(p) + '\n' + '\n'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple `div` tags with `class="bd"` on the page. Looks like you need the one that contains an actual article - it is inside of `article` tag:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Ask user to enter URL
url = raw_input("Please enter a valid URL: ")

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

# retrieve all of the paragraph tags
paragraphs = soup.find('article').find("div", {'class': 'bd'}).find_all('p')
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print paragraph.text
```

prints:

```
Libyan government forces on Monday seized a North Korea-flagged tanker after...
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1: Almost posted my variation but you got it first. Though, in mine, I had to add `encode("utf-8")` to my `print` line. Only difference is I used `requests` instead of `urllib2`.

Comment: @Nanashi thanks, usually I prefer `requests` too, but the OP uses `urllib2` - decided to make the code close to what the OP provided.

Comment: Thanks this worked great! Out of curiosity why do you prefer requests? I am new to python so I'm looking to learn everything I can atm.

Comment: lol I made the change. It stopped the code from breaking on quotes as well.